# DataGridView Refreshing Data by Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, api, datagridview

I'm working on a project to display the information received from the API in a DataGridView. I have created a Thread to update the DataGridView that runs the DataGridView refresh method every 5 seconds in a parallel process. But when the program runs, after one step of  the Thread, the information is placed in the DataGridView, I get this error in the second step of calling the "RefreshGridData" function by Thread:

*exception {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} System.NullReferenceException*

Here are the codes of the Thread and the DataGridView refresh function called by that:

**Data Refreshing Thread**

```
    {
        trdRefresh = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    RefreshGridData();
                    Thread.Sleep(1000 * 5);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000 * 5);
                }
            }
        });
        trdRefresh.Start();
    }
```

**RefreshGridData:**

```
                var response =  DataReceiver();
                var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ClientPulsLog>>(response);
                var source = new BindingSource
                {
                    DataSource = Data
                };

                DataGridView1.DataSource = source; //The error occurs here
                DataGridView1.Refresh();
```

**Data Receiver:**

```
    public static string DataReceiver()
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var client = new HttpClient())
                    {
                        var url = $"http://{"127.0.0.1:9094"}/DataProvider/TotalData/";
                        var request = "{\"MessageType\":"+ typeId + "}";
                        var content = client.GetAsync(url).GetAwaiter().GetResult().Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                        return content;
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
    
                }
                return string.Empty;
            }
```

**Important note** 
The interesting thing is that when I put a Watch Point at the beginning of the error line, whenever it arrives and pauses while debugging, if I wait a second and then click on the Continue button, the program will continue without any problems.

How can I solve this problem? 
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please highlight where exactly the NRE is thrown. Please also include the `DataReceiver`'s code. A sample json would be also beneficial. So, all in all please try to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You cannot do anything UI-related from a background thread. So at least the `DataGridView1.DataSource = source; DataGridView1.Refresh();` must be on the UI thread.

Comment: @PeterCsala Thank you. I added DataReceiver's code

Comment: @KlausGütter I didn't get that. How can I define a UI thread?

Comment: Are you using Winforms or WPF? For Winforms, you can execute code on the UI thread using `DataGridView1.Invoke(...)`. For WPF, it is `DataGridView1.Dispatcher.Invoke(...)`

Comment: @KlausGütter I'm using Winforms. Thank You! Trying to do that.

Comment: Use an async method to get the data from the API, hence remove all those chained `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` stuff and and `await` the async methods (as `await client.GetAsync()`). In case the JSON deserialization takes a lot of time time (?), you can Task.Run() that and await the result. -- HttpClient should be declared as a `static` Field, do not create an instance each time you query the API -- After that, set `DataGridView1.DataSource = null;`  before you reset it. Don't call `Refresh()`, this doesn't refresh the data, it repaint the Control, pretty useless, since it does it on its own.

Comment: Note that System.Text.Json provides an async [JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserializeasync) method that you can await in this context, which is the preferred way. -- System.Text.Json is also available in .Net Framework, adding its [NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json), in case it's needed.